# batch loading data bcp

Tags: sql, sql-server, bcp

I need to keep a track of data loaded into tables in a "batchlog" table. Before a table is loaded, I need to add a new row into this batchlog table with basic details like filename, tablename, date-time of the load. This is a simple Insert query that I need to fire which will create a new row into batchlog table.

sample data in "batchlog" table.

```
batchid filename    tablename   datatime
1       f1.dat      f1          2-Dec
2       f1.dat      f1          3-Dec
3       f2.dat      f2          13-Dec
4       f5.dat      f5          14-Dec
5       f3.dat      f3          20-Dec
6       f4.dat      f4          22-Dec
```

... and so on

Question/ Problem: 
I load data into my tables using BCP. All is working great. Except, now, there is an extra column, batchID, which will serve as a reference key to the "batchlog" table. Meaning, everytime, data is loaded into a table, eg "f1", it will have the latest batchid from batchlog table.

eg, table "F1", it has following columns...

```
id, name, batchid
1, ABC, 1
2, PQR, 1
3, ABC, 2
4, PQR, 2
```

How do I load data into the tables along with the latest "batchid" using BCP and format files?

Hope I have not confused anyone here :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are there multiple batch processes loading into the same table?

Comment: @samyi, at anygiven time, only 1 process will write into the same table. Data is loaded on a scheduled time.

Comment: You can load to a staging table that gets purged per load. Then you can add the new BatchId when moving it into its permanent home. There aren't any parameter driven bcp commands if that's what you're asking.